# Sidebar Slideshow widget with text

Tags: plugins, widgets

Can anyone suggest me some good sidebar slideshow widget? I need to add some text file along with each sides and show the image along with the text.

Eg:http://misys.com/products/bankfusion-universal-banking.aspx.
Please see the widget given here in the bottom of the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this StackExchange is meant to recommend plugins. However, I happen to have built this for a client before. It uses jQuery's "jCaroussel" plugin, and you can see it in action on [Oelers Makelaardij](http://oelersmakelaardij.nl/).

Scoop up the [minified version](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/blob/master/dist/jquery.jcarousel.min.js), it contains all plugins like Autoscrolling, Controls, etc.

## CSS

Most of the CSS is [provided with the plugin](https://github.com/jsor/jcarousel/tree/master/test). Add it to your style.css and change it to your needs.

## JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#slider').jcarousel({ // initiate the slider on this element
        'animation':    { 'duration': 800, 'easing': 'swing' },
        'wrap':         'circular',
        'vertical':     true
    });

    $('#slider').jcarouselAutoscroll({ autostart: true });
    $('.jcarousel-prev').jcarouselControl({ target: '-=1' });
    $('.jcarousel-next').jcarouselControl({ target: '+=1' });

    $('#slider li img').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('alt') != '') {
            var $caption = $(this).attr('alt');
            $caption = '<span class="caption">' + $caption + '</span>';
            $(this).before($caption);
        }
    });

});
```

The last function you see there is my custom code. It loops through all the slides in the slider, looks at the image's `alt` attribute, and extract the text therein. Then it injects a `span` element containing this text before the `img` element. With CSS styling I overlaid this text on the image.

```
.jcarousel li .caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 70px;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    background: #c31d1d;
    background: rgba(195,29,29,0.7);
}
```

## PHP / HTML

```
<a class="jcarousel-prev" href="#">Previous</a>
<div id="slider" class="jcarousel">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img alt="Overlay" src="" width="" height="" />My text
        </li>
        <li>
            <img alt="Overlay" src="" width="" height="" />My text
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<a class="jcarousel-next" href="#">Next</a>
```

This is the basic HTML structure to contruct a slideshow, but if you want to build it using WordPress' WYSIWYG editor, you can use the following code instead:

```
<div id="slider" class="jcarousel">
<?php
    $my_postid = 35; // change this to the ID of the post that contains the list of slides in an Unordered Bullet List
    $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    echo $content;
?>

</div>
```

Now you can build an unordered list in a post, insert image thumbnails and add text. With additional CSS styling you can position all your elements, like on Oelers Makelaardij (link at beginning of answer for working example).